# bumped vs faced

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Can anybody say me difference between **BUMPED** and **FACED**

PS

I heard in conversation:

> Yesterday I bumped with my friend.

Does it make sense? In meaning he met his friend accidentally.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Can I say:

> I bumped to some problem

or

> I faced with some problem

Sorry, but for me it sounds like same...

Comment: The expression is ***bump into***: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bump+into

Comment: What does the dictionary say?

Comment: What is your question about "faced"?

Comment: ***To face*** does not convey  the meaning you are referring to.

Comment: These questions are becoming more and more about English comprehension (learning) and have nothing to do with usage.

Answer (score 3):

Your question needs just a little correction, that I will edit after first explaining to you the words that you have mentioned.

Bump is a small knock or a bang, so this means literally, that you have bumped into each other physically; perhaps because you were both looking in different directions; or because it was so dark that you could not see.

So it is that we also use the same expression, when you meet an acquaintance without pre planning any meeting, unexpectedly; You are said to have "bumped" into each other.

Faced however, you seem to be misunderstanding somehow, to face someone is to turn to look at them, it can even be confrontational. To have 'faced up' to some thing or someone is to have dealt with something that was perhaps unpleasant or undesirable; to have acknowledged.

'To face facts' is a common term for acknowledging the reality of any situation and as mentioned in the comments below; to face a problem is to deal with it directly.

It is commonly said "to face up to someone", you might say "yesterday I have finally faced up to my fears and confronted them about the issue ..."
We may say also for accepting a situation or a turn of events "I will face the music".

Comment: It's also worth noting that to simply "face" a problem does not have as much of a negative connotation as to "face up" to a problem. The first implies merely dealing with it; the second implies dealing with something you have neglected or have been trying to avoid.

Comment: However "I was faced with a problem" is not particularly negative at all; it's a challenge to be overcome.

Answer (score 3):

I think you misheard.  There are some slang contexts in which the expression

> *Yesterday I bumped with my friend

could be correct, but it is **not** common usage at all.

The common form would be:

> Yesterday I bumped *into* my friend

You are right in the meaning: it is something like "I accidentally met my friend briefly"  For example, you might say this if you were walking to the shop and you met them while they were walking to work.  It implies that this was not planned.

The other two sentences that you suggest:

> *I bumped to some problem
>
> *I faced with some problem

Are not English.  "Bumped" is not commonly used with "problem".  I can't think of a natural way to make a correct sentence from that.

You can say one of these though:

> I faced a problem
>
> I faced some problems
>
> I was faced with a problem

"Bumped" literally means to collide lightly with something.  A car might bump into another car.  You might bump into someone when you walk around a corner and collide with another person.

"Faced" means that your face is pointed towards something.  You faced the sunset.  I faced the wall.  They faced each other.  It can be used metaphorically to mean that you encounter something, like a problem, deliberately with full attention.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, you probably mis-heard, or the person who overheard made a grammar error. We say "bumped into" -- not just "bumped" -- to mean "met by accident". So you might say, "I was at the store yesterday when I bumped into an old friend from college." Meaning, you were not planning to meet this person, the meeting was accidental.

Literally, to "bump" something is to run into it, but not in a way that is violent or destructive. Like you might say, "I was walking through the room in the dark and I bumped into a chair." If the impact is large, we'd use a different word. Like, "My car bumped into the sign post" would mean that you hit it, but there was little or no damage. "My car crashed into the sign post" means there is significant damage. So when we say you bumped into a person, it's a metaphor. You problably didn't literally collide with them. You just met them unexpectedly.

Similarly, you could say you "bumped into a problem" meaning that it came up unexpectedly. Like, "I was trying to get the Foobar Project wrapped up yesterday, when I bumped into a problem with the framnitz regulator."

To "face" is to point in a certain direction. Like, "I faced the window and looked out over the parking lot."

You can say that someone "faced a problem", meaning that he acknowledged it, he recognized that it was a problem. Like if you say, "Jack refuses to face the fact that his laziness will get him fired", you mean that he refuses to accept that this is a real issue. Conversely, "He faced his fears" means that he acknowledged that he was afraid and was prepared to deal with that fact.

Answer (score 2):

To go on an entirely different tack from the other answers, it is possible that you heard the statement correctly.  "Bumping" is a fad dance form from the 70's that has recently become somewhat popular again.  Here's a video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RheYzUWoxU

So, it's possible (although probably unlikely) that you heard the person say that he *bumped with a friend yesterday*, but if so it would mean that he was doing this dance with a friend the day before. It would not mean that he ran into him accidentally; as others have pointed out, that would be *bumped into*.  Also, to add to iain's answer, in addition to *facing up to* someone or something, you can also [*face down*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/face-down-someone-something) someone or something.